# make a dynamic tableview javaFX editable

Tags: javafx, tableview

I'm trying to make editable a table view dynamic in javaFX, i already have the dynamic table loading values from a object and works perfect, but i can't make this editable.

i create the dinamic table with this

```
ArrayList<reportes> rs = BD.ConsultarVarios(selecionado);
            for (int column = 1; column +1< rs.size(); column++) {
                tablevarios.getColumns().add(
                        createColumn(column, rs.get(column).getNombre()));
            }
            // Add data to table:
            ArrayList<ObservableList<StringProperty>> data = new ArrayList<>(FXCollections.observableArrayList());

            for (int i = 0; rs.get(0).getValor().size() > i; i++) {
                ObservableList<StringProperty> data2 = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
                for (int k = 0; rs.size() > k+1; k++) {
                    data2.add(new SimpleStringProperty(rs.get(k).getValor().get(i)));

                }
                data.add(data2);
                tablevarios.getItems().add(data.get(i));
            }
```

but when i try to make editable with this

```
                    tablevarios.getColumns().get(i).setCellFactory(column -> new EditCell());
```

i have this error from the console

> Error:(1687, 78) java: incompatible types: bad return type in lambda expression
>       sample.Main.EditCell cannot be converted to javafx.scene.control.TableCell,capture#1 of ?>

thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Does your EditCell extends ListCell ?

I did it in my project like this:

```
class EditCell extends ListCell<?> {
// your cell properties here
    @Override
        protected void updateItem(Object item, boolean empty) {
            super.updateItem(item, empty);
        }


tablevarios.getColumns().get(i).setCellFactory(lv -> {
        ListCell<?> cell = new EditCell();
        //maybe add context menu to cell or other thins
        return cell;
}
```